# differentiate between same class names

Tags: jquery

There are two section div sections with the same class and also has same ul and li and a. I have jquery click event. When the link is clicked both of the jquery click event are getting fired. But I do not want both, only one to be fired. How do I achieve this. This is the dom structure I have.

```
<div class = "a">
<ul>  
<li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li></ul></div>

<div class ="a">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.yahoo.com>yahoo</a></li></ul></div>
```

The href might change so I cannot base my selector on that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give them distinct IDs?

Comment: @jimw not needed.  Bet $1 it's how the event listeners are getting attached.  Please show us your JS code.

Comment: You're probably right, and you're certainly right about showing the code.

Answer (score 3):

Only one is being fired, you are just miss-interpreting what is happening. Try this:

```
$("div.a a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.href);
});
```

Post your code and we may be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first() method to fire the first one and last() to fire the last one.  Beyond that, you may have to implement unique IDs or apply another class:

```
http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/
```

Using another class:

```
<div class = "a google">  
<ul>    
<li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li></ul></div>  

<div class ="a yahoo">  
<ul>  
<li><a href="www.yahoo.com>yahoo</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the one with the correct href attribute:

```
$('a[href^="wwww.google"]').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('This is not the Google you are looking for...');
});
```

If the href changes, you have no way to distinguish them, there is no ID, class or difference in structure, so the only option would be to check the index they have in the DOM:

```
$('.a > ul > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var A = $(this).closest('.a').index();
    if (A==3) {
        alert("this is the one I'm lookin for");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(function(){ $('.a').click(function(){ var a = $(this).val(); alert(a); }); });
```